# Freebase to find alternative company names

Tags: java, freebase, named-entity-recognition

I am attempting to use Freebase to find all the alternative names of a specified company. I currently have the following code, which works when you specify the languages you want the name to be in. I would like it to return all alias, regardless of the language. However, if I do not specify the languages, no results are returned. Also, if I include all languages in the query as one long list, it returns results for the wrong company. When I did this in the below code, it returned results for Bank of America. Is there a way of specifying all languages? The main purpose of the code is to find common acronyms of companies, though select full names are useful too.

```
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory();
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search");

        url.put("query", "Royal Bank of Scotland");
        url.put("filter", "(all type:/organization/organization )");
        url.put("limit", "1");
        url.put("output", "( /common/topic/alias )");
        url.put("lang", "cs");//Specify Laungauges
        url.put("key", properties.get("API_KEY"));

        HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = request.execute();
        JSONObject response = (JSONObject)parser.parse(httpResponse.parseAsString());
        JSONArray results = (JSONArray)response.get("result");
        System.out.println(results);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lang` parameter takes a comma separated list of languages.  If you really want *all*, you can just use the entire list which currently is:

"en,es,fr,de,it,pt,zh,ja,ko,ru,sv,fi,da,nl,el,ro,tr,hu,th,pl,cs,id,bg,uk,ca,eu,no,sl,sk,hr,sr,ar,hi,vi,fa,ga,iw,lv,lt,gl,is,hy,lo,km,sq,fil,zxx"

From https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?help=langs&indent=true as documented on https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-cookbook#language-constraints

This query works for me:

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query="Royal%20Bank%20of%20Scotland"&filter=(all%20type:/organization/organization%20)&limit=1&output=(/common/topic/alias%20)&lang=en,es,fr,de,it,pt,zh,ja,ko,ru,sv,fi,da,nl,el,ro,tr,hu,th,pl,cs,id,bg,uk,ca,eu,no,sl,sk,hr,sr,ar,hi,vi,fa,ga,iw,lv,lt,gl,is,hy,lo,km,sq,fil,zxx

Comment: Yes, I had tried that but for some unknown reason, when you include the whole list of languages it returns incorrect results. When I tried it in the above code it gave me alternate names for Bank of America as opposed to RBS, while when I only included cs,el the expected results were returned. Also tried * and all with no success.

Comment: I can't reproduce your results.  I've edited my reply to include a working query.